# Let f be a function defined on $R$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$; $x,y $ $\in R $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a function defined on $R$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$; $x,y $ $\in R $.

If f is differentiable at one point of $R$ then prove that f is differentiable on $R
$.

Comment: f(x^n)= n f(x); f(1)=0; similarly f'(1)={f(1+h)-f(1)}/h = 0. so, f is differentiable on R. please correct me, I am not sure.

Comment: Please edit your question to add further insights. (and mark them as additions.) -- The differentiability is a ruse, you only need continuity (and even less) in one point. -- Do you see that from your first insight also $f(\sqrt[m]x)=\frac1mf(x)$ follows?

Comment: The question would make more sense for $x,y \gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
f(x\cdot 0)=f(0)+f(x)\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x)=0.
\end{align}